# Nesting lists with the APA document class

Tags: lists, apa-style

When writing lists, sometimes I need to make lists within lists:

```
\documentclass{apa}
\begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item This is an item.
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item This is another item.
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

With the APA document class, this seems to produce a list with "1. 1.", but the second item is not deeper. How can I make a nested list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `apa6e` class does what you want.

As far as I can tell, both `apa` and `apa6e` conform to the (different) guidelines for *manuscript submissions* to APA, so they aren't really useful for producing standalone documents (and indeed the resulting appearance is ugly).

These classes are aimed to producing "format independent" LaTeX documents, that will be later reshaped to conform the style of the various journals of APA.

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation of the `apa` class, `enumerate` and `itemize`

> are used in the same way the standard LaTeX environments `enumerate` and
>   `itemize` are used, but produce output according to the APA style.

If you really want standard-style list environments, load the [enumitem](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package.

```
\documentclass{apa}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item This is an item.
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item This is another item.
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Does this mean, people wishing to conform to the APA style cannot use lists in this way?

Comment: @Village: I'd presume so (though I'm not versed in APA's requirements).